# Which SE site is a good place to ask about removing SFF custom CSS themes?

Tags: discussion, design

Meaning no offense to Jin, the current SFF theme is murder on my eyes (my eyes are probably more at fault than the designer :)

I'm rather weak at CSS-fu, especially on the user side (e.g. fixing CSS in the browser for sites I don't control).

What would be a good SE site to ask this question on? (e.g. "How can I remove the SFF specific design and replace it with StackOverflow standard design?)

Comment: I have a Chrome extension that could be adapted for this site that exchanges the CSS, if you're interested.

Comment: @MadScientist - can it exchange CSS for SO's CSS? If so, most definitely interested. (I don't suppose it matters if SO's CSS is in a single downlodable file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a Chrome extension that switches out the CSS for that of any other SE site. I created a version that uses the default beta theme on Scifi ( https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21284684/scifi.crx ). Just drag that file onto the chrome://extensions site and it will be installed.

Here are the source files if you want to change anything:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21284684/scifi/manifest.json

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/21284684/scifi/scifitheme.js

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks! I also packaged a clone for meta.

Answer (score 3):

I posted a guide on how to get started with user CSS [over on Superuser](https://superuser.com/a/465964/94278), so I'd suggest going over that if you're looking to bone up on user CSS.