# Could meta's inverted colours be uninverted?

Tags: feature-request, design

While I basically don't dislike meta's white on black, my having to sit in front of a PC screen most of the day with lots of black on white text means that visiting meta severely shifts contrast. [We had the same issue back on physics.SE *main*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/447) and while [Jin](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/44/jin) does a great job in his designs, this strong change from white-on-black to black-on-white when visiting meta is *really* uncomfortable to my eyes, and judging from the reactions on physics.SE that ultimately led to a new, non-inverted, theme I'm not alone here. So, could this meta's color scheme be adapted more to what is common in the internet?

*sidenote* There are also people who invert their screen colours *on purpose* due to eye strain etc., and for them meta suddenly appears in bright white, which probably is even more unpleasant when unexpected...

Comment: Potentially relevant: ["most studies have shown that dark characters on a light background are superior to light characters on a dark background"](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/568/7228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very well, as Keen [suggested](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3159/769), here's my own solution, a userscript which simply applies the parent CSS.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        let meta.scifi.SE use parent CSS
// @namespace   zommuter
// @description let meta.scifi.SE use parent CSS
// @include     https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link")

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    if(link.rel === "stylesheet") {
        link.href = link.href.replace("meta", "")
    }
}

var anchs = document.getElementById('hlogo').getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0; i<anchs.length; i++) {
    anchs[i].style.background = 'url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/scifimeta/img/logo.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent';
}
```

Comment: I added the CSS change to the userscript.

Comment: @Keen Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See the answers on [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2334/1027) for some options on how you can make these changes on your end.

Comment: The answer there only works for Chrome, but [your SU post](http://superuser.com/a/465964/35237) covers FF. Nonetheless, I'm not the only one concerned by this issue, and you _may_ turn users away from meta by making this a "fix it for yourself only" issue - especially when the fix needs maintenance everytime the engine slightly changes the CSS, and not everyone is motivated into doing this just to participate here...

Comment: Very well, [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3161/769)'s my go...